# Find and replace by multiple patterns

Tags: google-sheets

Suppose I've got a text values column (named *Data*), generated by *=unique()* function. Also, there is an array of patterns to find and replace for (*Find* and *Replace* columns).

Which formula should I use to scan each cell in *Data* for multiple patterns in *Find* and replace it, if match?

```
   Data Find Replace Result
1  a    c    z       a
2  b    f    y       b
3  c    e    x       z
4  d                 d
5  e                 x
6  c                 z
```

Tried *=SUBSTITUTE()* and *=IF()* functions, but it fails, when I set an array of patterns, instead of single one.

Comment: 1. Will it always be the entire string being replaced, as in this example, or could it be a part of the string? 2. If the latter, is it possible that more than one substring needs to be replaced within one string? 3. Will the replacement always be one character?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's entire string.
2. Can you explain, what is substring?
3. No, all strings contains some sentenses

Comment: 2. If you mean *Data* column, than yes, it has duplicates (non unique values), which should be replaced with the first one.

Comment: OK, say you had this for one of the Data cells: `Magic carpet ride`, and in the the Find list you had `magic car` and `ride` with a valid replacement. Would both of these get replaced?

Comment: Ah, I realized where the problem is. Actually I can add to Find list only full names. Say, in Data column there is 2 cells, named `Magic carpet ride`. And I only want to replace both with `Dust collector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table you is in range A1:E7, try this formula

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE($B$2:$B$7&"|")),$C$2,$D$2),$C$3,$D$3),$C$4,$D$4),"|"))
```

You can read further about this [in an older post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/multiple-substitutions-in-a-single-text) and [google docs forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/DVuuP5POwvE).

Comment: It works fine. Is there any way to do the same, but with the autoupdate?
In your formula, i should manually add one more REGEXREPLACE for each new replace pattern.

Comment: Not that I know of, the easiest way to do it would be with a script. Formulas like REGEXREPLACE and SUBSTITUTE can not work with multiple options

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$4,MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$4,0)),A2)` is shorter and does the same

Answer (score 0):

**Array solution**

This formula takes range to replace, so it can be used for variable number of patterns:

`=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({REGEXMATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$4),
REGEXREPLACE(A2,$B$2:$B$4,$C$2:$C$4)}),
"select Col2 order by Col1 desc limit 1")`

or this one:

```
=INDEX(ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(A2,$B$2:$B$4,$C$2:$C$4)),IFERROR(MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$4,0),1))
```

or this:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$4,MATCH(A2,$B$2:$B$4,0)),A2)`

The formula is need to be dragged down.

---

**Single Formula & Array solution**

Also this single ArrayFormula will do the trick:

`=ArrayFormula(trim(transpose(query({IF(--REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(A2:A7),$B$2:$B$4)=1,
REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(A2:A7),$B$2:$B$4,$C$2:$C$4),"");
TRANSPOSE(if(--not(REGEXMATCH(A2:A7,JOIN("|",B2:B4))),A2:A7,""))},,COUNTA(A2:A)))))`

or this shorter formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MATCH(A2:A7,B2:B4,0),{ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&COUNTA(C2:C4))),C2:C4},2,0),A2:A7))`

Please, see explanations in [Sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XumxcODvio9d8tvk_i_At2VHnRiZjRM2UkwXs80tBF8/edit#gid=183299395)