# Find words in list and delete in text

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

Suppose I've got a text values column (named Data), generated by =unique() function. Also, there is an column (named find). Data in "find" must be deleted

Which formula should I use to scan each cell in DATA for words in FIND and delete it, if match?

```
   A    B    C
1  Data Find Result
2  abc  a    b
3  cd   c    d
4  f         f
```

I've tried this one, but can't delete the words that are found:
[Find and replace by multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371478/find-and-replace-by-multiple-patterns)

Comment: I want all data from row B to be removed. Right now, it only deletes data from the first row B data. Sow C2 now is BC but should be only B

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`=REGEXREPLACE(A2,B2,"")` and then just drag down

[image]

## Reference

[REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)

P.S. You can try `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "[^"&B2&"]")` but it is more tricky and you have to find a correct pattern

Answer (score -1):

I need to search for every word in column B in colum A and then delete word found from A as result in C

```
 A                               B                  C
1 search                         negativ            result                 delete
2 and this is                    is                 and this               is
3 here is another one            one                here another           is | one
4 this will be good              be                 this will good      
5 now here nice                                     now here nice
```

Comment: This works just fine: =REGEXREPLACE(A2;"a|c";"") but jeg need to write something like =REGEXREPLACE(A2;"B2:B";"") were B2:B are looking for all words in colum B